# Using has many through relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

How can I get or display **company** column from **contractors table** to put it in my blade? I already try figured it out by using hasManyThrough relationship but it doesn't work since all example that I made reference to is not having the same flow with me.

**contractors table**

```
id 
company
```

**residentials table**

```
id
contractor_id
```

**buyers table**

```
id
residential_id
```

This is the Model

**Contractor.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contractor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contractors';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','company','address','phone_no','email','avatar'];

    public function residential()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Residential::class);
    }

    public function buyers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Buyer', 'App\Residential');
    }

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Buyer', 'App\Residential');
    }
}
```

If I do this kind of code, it will be $contractor->buyer. While I want it to be $buyer->contractor->company

**Buyer.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Buyer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['buyer_id', 'name', 'address', 'phone_no', 'email', 'avatar', 'user_id', 'residential_id'];

    public function residential()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Residential::class);
    }
}
```

**Residential.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Residential extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','res_code','postcode','city','state','image','contractor_id'];

    public function contractor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contractor::class);
    }

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Buyer::class);
    }
}
```

**BuyerController.php**

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->role == 'buyer')
            {
                $buyers = Buyer::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->first();
                return view('buyers.index',['buyer'=>$buyers]);
            }
```

This is the view that I'm working on and there is no looping since this is a profile for buyers login.

**index.blade.php**

```
<h4 class="heading"><b><center>Buyer's Details</center></b></h4>
<ul class="list-unstyled list-justify">
    <li><b>Buyer ID: </b>{{$buyer->buyer_id}}</li>
    <li><b>Name: </b>{{$buyer->name}}</li>
    <li><b>Address: </b>{{$buyer->address}}</li>
    <li><b>Residence: </b>{{$buyer->residential->name}}</li>
    <li><b>Phone Number: </b>{{$buyer->phone_no}}</li>
    <li><b>Email: </b>{{$buyer->email}}</li>
    <li><b>Contractor: </b>{{$buyer->contractor->company}}</li>
</ul>
```

Based on the above view code, I already did the the relationship for **Residence:** But I'm not able to do it for **Contractor:** I hope there is someone to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

then u can do

```
$buyer->contractor->company
```

to

```
$buyer->residential->contractor->company
```

u have alredy added `belongsTo` added to 2 model

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through check here i did as here mentions

Comment: I got this error. Call to undefined relationship [contractor] on model [App\Buyer].

Comment: Currently, this is in my **Contractor.php** ```  public function residential()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Residential::class);
    } ``` **Buyer.php** ``` public function residential()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Residential::class);
    } ``` **Residential.php** ```    public function contractor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contractor::class);
    }

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Buyer::class);
    } ```

Comment: The previous one is correct. I forgot to delete something in my controller and I'm so sorry. Thank you so much for helping me!!

Comment: @IrdinaZulkeflee okay i m updating and u mark this answer then

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
$buyers = Buyer::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->first();
    return view('buyers.index',['buyer'=>$buyers]);
```

then call in blade file

```
$buyers->residential->contractor->company
```

Comment: This error I got. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'residentials.buyer_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `contractors`.*, `residentials`.`buyer_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `contractors` inner join `residentials` on `residentials`.`id` = `contractors`.`residential_id` where `residentials`.`buyer_id` in (7))